# When using canvas capturestream and mediastreamRecorder, if I switch tabs and go back, browser crashes

Tags: html5-canvas, webrtc, recording, web-mediarecorder, capturestream

I am recording canvas using captureStream method and mixing it with an audio using mediastream.addTrack.
But when i switch tabs and comeback the browser tab crashes. If i donot change the tab, it working. What will be the issue? Please share thoughts

Comment: Which browser? Browsers should never crash. File a bug, not an SO question.

Comment: chrome browser.